# How do I salvage my dried up lemon tree?

Tags: citrus, lemons, dryness

my lemon tree is about 2 years old and it was in good shape. I went on vacation this month and the tree wasn't watered for 2 weeks. Now all the leaves are dried up and the stem feels dry too. I scratched the bark and it's still green inside. Whay do I do to salvage it?

Comment: Not much you can do except water when the soil feels dry, and just wait to see if it puts out new growth.